# How to select the first row of a set of select statements fast

Tags: sql-server, union

I have got a bunch of SQL Statements. They are in a special order so if the first statement returns a row I am done, if not go to the next Statement and return the result. What would be a fast way to do this? I tried to realize it in T-SQL because I am on a MSSQL Server but it's really slow.

It's really important to make this thing as fast as possible.

Comment: "It's really important to make this thing as fast as possible." I think you should post an example (what you've tried and how it didn't work), schema, demo data, desired output, etc.

Comment: Please provide the query, strip names if you're worried about that, but the performance hit is difficult to determine without it.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the first row use [`TOP 1`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but as soon as one SQL Statement returns 1 row I am finished!

Comment: With appropriate logic checking @@rowcount to decide whether to move to the next query, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Select column1 from myTable
if @@ROWCOUNT <> 0 return

Select column1 from myOtherTable
if @@ROWCOUNT <> 0 return

... and so on
```

Comment: That's exactly the solution which I am using, but it's too slow.

Comment: In that case you'll probably have to look at the queries individually - see if you can optimize them, perhaps a better choice of indices, etc.  Is there any way you can post your SQL?  See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org) for some non-sql suggestions that you probably already know about how to isolate this better.  Good luck!